# Pattern for Degrees Minutes Seconds string and concert to different value

Tags: java

i trying to substring dms value into different values using regEX i am using java

```
example: 
32°12'40" to degree = 31,minute=12, seconds=40
32°40" to degree = 31,seconds=40
12'40" to minute=12, seconds=40
12' to minute=12
```

i tried lot of regEx but it failed please help me how to convert into different values in different conditions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (! dms.isEmpty()) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+)°)?(?:(\\d+)')?(?:(\\d+)\")?");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(dms);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String degree = m.group(1);
        String minute = m.group(2);
        String second = m.group(3);
        // Use values here. They are null if not given
    }
}
```